# Respond to the system shutdown process

Tags: vb6, hook, shutdown

I built a VB6 application to run in the background and tell me when my caps lock key gets cycled. It starts when Windows starts, so it's always on, but when I go to shutdown the computer, the app hangs the shutdown process in Windows 8.

Is there a system-wide event to monitor, or some other method of catching the shutdown command I can use to kill my app gracefully?

Comment: what win version did you compile in

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to be notified of a system shutdown is via `Form_QueryUnload()`. When the OS is shutting down, the `UnloadMode` parameter will be equal to `vbAppWindows`. For example:

```
Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)
    If UnloadMode = vbAppWindows Then

        ' OS is shutting down. Close gracefully.

    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can subclass your window and listen for the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` message.